# Selecting the Tag of NSSegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nssegmentedcontrol

I'm attempting to implement an NSSegmentedControl button in my IB.

I have it connected to `- (IBAction)editCart:(id)sender;`

Also, it is connected to `NSSegmentedControl *editCartButton;`

The first "segment" is a "-" button to decrease the cart value.
The second "segment" is a "+" button to increase the cart value.

When I attempt to use the "sender" value like so: `[sender selectedSegment]`, I get an error:
`-[NSTableView selectedSegment]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100622aa0`

My button is located inside an NSTableView.

I've also tried: `[[editCartButton cell] selectedTag]`

When I run it through my conditions, it always returns a value of (null).
I would like to retrieve the specific tags of 0 and 1 I'm expecting to get, but can't find the right actions.

Help appreciated greatly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
-[NSTableView selectedSegment]: unrecognized selector
                                sent to instance 0x100622aa0
```

basically tells you that the `sender` is not the `NSSegmentedControl` you think it is. The `sender` is an `NSTableView`. So either you wired things up the wrong way, or you have a severe memory management problem where the `NSSegmentedControl` is deallocated, and an `NSTableView` is currently to be found at its memory location.

In `-(IBAction)editCart:(id)sender` you could add a line:

```
NSLog(@"editCart, sender = %@",sender);
```

to confirm this. You can drop `NSLog` lines like this in other places in your code, to verify your ideas about what should be happening.

Comment: I did this and confirms that the `sender` is indeed `NSTableview`.
I re-wired everything and am getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm not understanding how it works properly, should I be doing :
- Connecting the NSSegmentedCell to something like 
`IBOutlet NSSegmentedControl *editCartButton;`

or
- Connecting the NSSegmentedCell to a function like 
`- (IBAction)editCart:(id)sender;`

Comment: You should be linking an *action* of NSSegmentedCell to the `IBAction` outlet of your view controller. In IB, there are two kinds of links: A) those referencing only objects (marked `IBOutlet` in your code), and B) those referencing a target (which is an object) and a selector (marked `IBAction` in your code; the method name is the selector, the containing object is the object). (However, you may also have a memory issue at hand, which messes up your links. We cannot see that from what you've posted.)

Answer (score -1):

in IBAction try replacing (id) with (UISegmentedControl *)

Comment: That would only work if the project was on iOS. As `NSSegmentedControl` is mentioned, I'm assuming that the targeted OS is OS X.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem when working on updating Seashore (A port of GIMP to native OS X APIs).

First, you have to get `NSSegmentedControl`'s cell object:

```
NSSegmentedControl *segControl = ...
NSSegmentedCell *segCell = [segControl cell];
```

Then, you set the tag for the segment you want to modify:

```
[segCell setTag:200 forSegment:2];
```

More info is available in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SegmentedControl/Articles/SegmentedControlCode.html).